# I I try to use reality composer but it doesn't work

Tags: xcode, virtual-machine, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have macOS installed on VMware and when I run Reality Composer from Xcode it doesn't work.

I tried upgrading the system to macOS 13.5 and Xcode to 14.3.1 and still nothing works.

I tried to run a simple AR project and it didn't work either.
I connected to my real ipad pro 3th and when i click run i get this error:
`Could not determine generated file paths for RC project code generation: The command` (cd /Users/Desktop/Char1 && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/rctool generate '--dry-run=true' '-o=/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Char1-bhtbjslbezngnjcjckqsdvxdowtc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Char1.build/Debug-iphoneos/Char1.build/DerivedSources/RCProjectGenerated/Experience' /Users/Desktop/Char1/Char1/Experience.rcproject '--swift-version=5.0')` exited with status 1. The command's standard error was:

[91mError:[39m There is no available Metal device on this system.

`

Comment: did you find a good way to solve that ?